# Wireshark showing post parameters in diffrent locations in follow TCP stream window

Tags: http, post, tcp, wireshark, postman

Im running some tests on a app and Ive stumbled upon an odd thing that happends when I sniff the traffic between me and the app server using wireshark:

In a scenario when Im making the post request through the app's html, it looks like that:
[image: making the post request through the app's html]

But when Im requesting the same thing using the chrome extension *"postman"*, it looks like that:

[image]

why are the parameters are now shown at the top of the request? I mean, what changed here?

Im trying to find a clue why is it working in the first option and refuses to work on the second. thats why I need to investigate every little thing..

**Edit:**

I wrote a short html page to illustrate this and the second option happens here as well:

```
...
<form action="http://x.x.x.x/page.cgi?id=1726931735&host_name=blah" method="post">
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postman` will send an empty body by default, you need to [enable the rows of key-value fields for them to be added to the request](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/keyvalue_editor).  `postman` does not read the `form` on the page, its parameters **must** be inserted into the plugin fields.  Otherwise `postman` will send an empty request just like you see.

You need to enter the fields in the `Body` tab in `postman`:

[image: postman boy tab]

Comment: That's right I think Ive just placed the parameters at the wrong place in postman.. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

It's very odd. The first one is correct. The second is using get semantics but doing a post with no content. I'd try something else instead of this chrome extension.